# How to save email sorted by date?

Tags: mutt

I seem to remember a patch to mutt that allowed to modify the path of the mailbox in mbox-hook in include the date.  For example, you could have this:

```
mbox-hook Maildir +Archive/%y/%m/maildir
```

Which would save the emails in Archive/2011/12/maildir if they were send during December 2011.

Anyone knows what it was called or if it still is supported?  I seem to remember that there was an option in the BSD ports to enable it but cannot find it now.

If not, does anyone know how I could achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called [mbox-hook supporting printf-like sequnces in mailbox](http://www.woolridge.org/mutt/mbox-hook.html).  Sadly, it appears not to be maintained any more.

However, it appears that you can still use the patch if you know how to code.